# Como impedir que usuário informe números para um determinado dado?

Tags: java, validação, números

Como eu faço para que meu programa Java não aceite números como dado informado pelo utilizador?

Gostaria que, em um campo que exige o nome do utilizador, caso um número seja inserido, como um crachá, faça com o que programa peça novamente o nome.

Já pensei em várias opções como fazer um "alfabeto de números", mas não sei se em Java será a melhor opção.

Comment: Você está usando swing, jsp, javafx, console ou o que?

Comment: Aqui não tem *dislike*, aqui tem avaliação do esforço da pessoa para postar e a sua utilidade e clareza. Assim como não tem *like* (tem no Facebook, por isso que o conteúdo lá é todo irrelevante, as pessoas gostam ou não gostam das coisas, gosto não ajuda ninguém evoluir, aprender, por isso aqui o gosto não tem vez), não é para votar no que você gosta ou não gosta e sim no que é útil ou não, se é claro ou não.

Comment: A usar netbeans

Comment: O netbeans é apenas o ambiente em que você desenvolve. O usuário não usa netbeans. O usuário entra com os nomes como? E o que constitui exatamente um nome válido e um nome inválido? `Pedro da Silva` é válido? `12345` é válido? `XN500$` é válido? `Martelo Verde` é válido?

Answer (score 7):

Um modo que você pode utilizar para verificar se uma sequência contém ou não certos caracteres é através de expressões regulares, no Java você pode usar o método [`String.Matches()`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/data/comparestrings.html), esse método retorna *true* se a sequência dada como parâmetro corresponder a uma determinada *regex*.

Na prática seria algo assim:

```
public boolean checkLetters(String str) 
{
    return str.matches("[a-zA-Z]+");
}
```

Exemplo:

```
public Main()
{
    Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);
    System.out.println("Digite o seu nome: ");
    String nome = sc.nextLine().trim();
    if (checkLetters(nome))
    {
        // Fazer alguma coisa aqui.
    }
    else
    {
        System.out.println("Neste campo não é permitido números. Tente Novamente.");
    }
}
```

Demonstração no [**Ideone**](http://ideone.com/0cJObE).

Answer (score 5):

Você pode criar um método único que recebe como argumento a `String` a ser verificada se há números ou não. Por exemplo:

```
public boolean hasNumbers(final String string){
   String numbers = "0123456789";
   for(char a : string.toCharArray())
     for(char b : numbers.toCharArray())
       if(a == b) return true;
   return false;
}
```

Assim você pode usá-lo em qualquer aplicação, seja ela Swing, console ou web.

---

#### Console

```
Scanner input = new Scanner(System.in);
if(hasNumbers(input.nextLine())){
   // tem números, faz algo...
}
```

#### Swing

```
String input = textField.getText(); // pega o valor no jtextfield
if(hasNumbers(input)){
   // tem números, faz algo...
}
```

---

Teste no [Ideone](http://ideone.com/N7dmbP).

Veja também a [resposta do QMechanic73](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/43927/4808) usando *regex*.

Answer (score 4):

Supondo que você esteja usando console, você pode fazer algo assim:

```java
public static String lerNome(String mensagem, Scanner scanner) {
    while (true) {
        System.out.println(mensagem);
        String lido = scanner.nextLine().trim();
        if (lido.isEmpty()) {
            System.out.println("Desculpe, você não digitou nada. Tente novamente.");
            continue;
        }
        try {
            new BigDecimal(lido);
            System.out.println("Desculpe, mas " + lido + " é um número. Você deveria ter digitado um nome. Tente novamente.");
        } catch (NumberFormatException e) {
            return lido;
        }
    }
}
```

E então você usaria este método assim:

```java
Scanner ent = new Scanner(System.in);
String nome = lerNome("Digite o nome.", ent);
```

Este código mostra a mensagem `Digite o nome.` e lê uma linha de texto lida do usuário. Se esta linha de texto estiver em branco ou for um número, ele dá uma mensagem de erro e não sai do loop, pedindo para o usuário digitar novamente. Caso contrário (não está em branco e não é número), ele aceita e retorna o texto digitado.

Answer (score 2):

Só Colocar Isso No Evento KeyReleased:

```
char[] text = txt.getText().toCharArray();

if (txt.getText().length() > 0){

    for (int i = 0; i < text.length; i++){
        if (text[i] >= '0' && text[i] <= '9'){
            txt.setText(txt.getText().replace(String.valueOf(text[i]), ""));
        }
    }
}
```

Já que você usa Netbeans não será difícil adicioná-lo, selecione a Textbox, vá em eventos no canto inferior direito e procura KeyReleased.

Comment: Essa Sua Capitalização Das Iniciais Torna Tudo Mais Difícil De Ler, Não Acha?

Comment: @bfavaretto Provavelmente, Vou Tentar Deixar Essa Mania De Lado Pelo O Menos Aqui No Stack.

Comment: Você usa alguma extensão pra fazer isso ou é manualmente com o shift? Somente por curiosidade.

Comment: @renan Na Verdade A Cada Palavra Eu Aperto Caps Lock É Instintivo E Rápido.

Comment: Caracas, isso meio que dá agonia.